# Add extra HTML markup to features in Wagtail RichTextField editor?

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-admin, draftail

How can I add extra HTML markup to individual features in Wagtail's RichTextField and have it be stored in the database? Specifically, I need to change the default appearance of a rendered `<ul>` list, so it would use custom font icons instead of bullet points.

So instead of a `<ul>` list like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

It would save the following in the database:

```
<ul>
    <li><i class="bx bx-chevron-right">Item 1</li>
    <li><i class="bx bx-chevron-right">Item 2</li>
    <li><i class="bx bx-chevron-right">Item 3</li>
    <li><i class="bx bx-chevron-right">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the wagtail's draftail editor. See [Creating new blocks](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/extending/extending_draftail.html#creating-new-blocks)